# CFStream Socket send packet not complete in IOS 7.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, ios7, cfstream

I use CFStream Socket send data to Host.
The first send is work. 
But after first, the data recv by host always be sperated.
For example:

First time Send:

```
Sender:  <11223344 55667788>
Recver:  <11223344 55667788>
```

ok it's good

second time, third time...

```
Sender:  <11223344 55667788>
Recver:  <11>
Recver:  <223344 55667788>
```

This symptom only happened in IOS 7.0.
There are no this symptom in 6.0, 5.0...

```
enter code here
CFReadStreamRef inputStream;
CFWriteStreamRef outputStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)_owner.ip, _owner.port, &inputStream, &outputStream);
NSDictionary *sslSettings = @{(id)kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain: (id)kCFBooleanFalse};
CFReadStreamSetProperty(inputStream, kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1);
CFReadStreamSetProperty(inputStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(sslSettings));
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(outputStream, kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(outputStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(sslSettings));
_inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)inputStream;
[_inputStream setDelegate:self];
[_inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

_outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)outputStream;
[_outputStream setDelegate:self];
[_outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[_inputStream open];
[_outputStream open];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the 1/n-1 split technique to mitigate BEAST attacks. http://threatpost.com/apple-turns-on-safari-beast-attack-mitigation-by-default-in-os-x-mavericks/102804

Your server probably only supports TLS 1.0. If you upgrade your server to support TLS 1.2, I believe iOS will stop doing this.